# Replace 00 decimals in Magento to 'minus'

Tags: magento, decimal

I have a Magento webshop, available in Dutch (NL) and English.

There are different products, but all cost 1.00 euro. I managed to get the price to 1.00 in English and 1,00 in Dutch.

Now, what I want is to edit the decimals in Dutch. I want to display 1,00 as 1,-

This is a common Dutch format when the decimals are 00. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest/Dirty way is to go to your PACKAGE/THEME folder and hunt down:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Then do `str_replace( ',00', ',-', $fPrice );`

A better way is to copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
```

Into 
    app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php

And do the str_replace there:

line 153:

```
return str_replace( ',00', ',-', Mage::app()
->getStore()
->formatPrice($price, $includeContainer) );
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked better for me. This because I couldn't exactly find which class='price' was showing on my frontend and there are a lot of instances of price in the file.

One thing; I didn't have a app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/ map, so I backupped the data.php in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php as data-backup.php and edited the original file. That worked for me.

Comment: The local file will override automatically do just create it and voila.